# How do I know which button is clicked in the popup window when using QFileDialog.getSaveFileName

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I am using QFileDialog module, and I encounter a problem: how do I know which button is clicked (save or cancel) in the popup window when using QFileDialog.getSaveFileName in PyQt5:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()` method returns an empty string if the file was not chosen, that is, when the cancel button is pressed, and instead a non-empty string when the save button is pressed:

```py
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()
if filename:
    print("The save button is pressed")
else:
    print("The cancel button is pressed")
```